# mongodb shell is written in JavaScript. Why UNIX binary then?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, shell

Is that true, that MongoDB shell is written in JavaScript?

If yes why it's a UNIX binary? Not a webapp for browser?

```
> less /usr/local/bin/mongo                            
"/usr/local/bin/mongo" may be a binary file.  See it anyway?       
> file /usr/local/bin/mongo                            
/usr/local/bin/mongo: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

Comment: The mongo shell accepts JavaScript code. What makes you think it is implemented in JavaScript? This is like thinking the bash shell (which is implemented in C) was implemented in bash script...

Comment: Furthermore, Javascript runs on UNIX outside the browser as well...

Comment: Never heard of nodejs? Look into it.

Comment: @fyodor78 Maybe you should learn from the pros http://university.mongodb.com - free, packed with information, and done by the vendor. You can't ask for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mongo shell, as well as the mongod database process are implemented in C++. You can get the source code and build it yourself here: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo

Comment: This is not true! For instance, this is the implementation of the .count() method: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/shell/query.js#L377 - JavaScript! You will see the same when you enter this in the mongo shell: `db.myCollection.find().count`

Comment: @nexus, most of the API is written in JavaScript, but the shell that runs those functions is written in C++.